# Parsing handshake.headers['cookie']

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, socket.io

I want to read cookies with this code:

```
handshake.headers['cookie']
```

And i get this result:

```
io=MqkoVEvAz4boRo_2AAAA; connect.sid=s%3AERNo3MbdeK5ymjMcNX4r8gatIoOAOJ3j.dr1w1A%2Fj9FqFZBCJAnjA6qhNAFaD8Us5ZZDgh2D%2BHvc; locale=fa; mongo-express=s%3AzD796V1RCrPNy8QIvdvPEoxU.%2B9mlaRS1sloBgD1kGEWr%2BUmI1PSonEaV1svsHBsjvBM
```

But how i can get only `locale` value? how i can parse this string?

Comment: Node.js doesn't come with anything to modify/read individual cookies in the Cookie header. Since you're using Express, try using `handshake.cookies` instead.

Comment: You can get all headers with request method.

Comment: @Blender: i want to fetch cookie inside socket.io, when i write this i get undefined: console.error(client.handshake.cookies);